# How could you match a set of values to a set of intervals in any order?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like so, containing the coordinates of some points in 3d space. The points are defined as intervals to allow for some tolerance:

```
Point1_X_INTVL | Point1_Y_INTVL | Point1_Z_INTVL | Point2_X_INTVL | Point2_Y_INTVL | Point2_Z_INTVL | ...
   (0.0 - 0.5) |    (0.0 - 0.5) |    (0.0 - 0.5) |    (1.0 - 1.5) |    (1.0 - 1.5) |    (1.0 - 1.5) | ...
```

And I have a set of points `[(1.022, 1.222, 1.223), (0.012, 0.111, 0.222)]`.

I want to check that any ordering of the points in the set matches with the entry in the dataframe. So a query with this set of points should return a match with the entry (and all other entries where the points are within the ranges), because the first point matches the second set of intervals in the dataframe, and the second matches the first. A point should not be able to match with the same interval twice: `[(1.022, 1.222, 1.223), [(1.022, 1.222, 1.223)]` would not be a match. All the points must match a set of intervals for the query to match the entry.

I am able to restructure the data if that is considered the best course of action. In the true formulation of this problem, there are around a dozen points to match, not just two, and the number of intervals in the entry may be different than the number of points in the query (again, it is not a match unless every point matches a interval, and there are no unmatched intervals or points).

Comment: I feel like there would need to be a backtracking algorithm to properly check all the combinations...

Comment: This can be phrased as an optimization problem and modelled with mixed integer programming.